# Can I avoid the need for authentication when testing Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I am trying to use DRF testing for the first time, so I created the following TestCase:

```
class TestInventoryActionInputNoSeriable(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.repository = create_repository()
        self.not_seriable_product = create_not_seriable_product()

    def test_post_inventory_input_not_seriable(self):
        client = APIClient()

        response = client.post('/api/inventory/execute_action/', {
            'action': 'input',
            'repository': self.repository.id,
            'product': self.not_seriable_product.id,
            'amount': 1,
        })
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        inventory_actions = models.InventoryAction.objects.all()
        inventory_inputs = models.InventoryInput.objects.all()
        kardexs = models.Kardex.objects.all()

        self.assertEqual(len(inventory_actions), 1)
        self.assertEqual(len(inventory_inputs), 1)
        self.assertEqual(len(kardexs), 1)

        inventory_action = inventory_actions.first()
        inventory_input = inventory_inputs.first()
        kardex = kardexs.first()

        self.assertEqual(inventory_action.action_content_type.model, 'inventoryinput')
        self.assertEqual(inventory_action.action_object_id, inventory_input.id)
        self.assertEqual(kardex.type, models.KARDEX_INPUT)
        self.assertEqual(kardex.repository_id, self.repository_id)
        self.assertEqual(kardex.product_id, self.not_seriable_product.id)
        self.assertEqual(kardex.amount, 1)
        self.assertEqual(kardex.stock, 1)
```

But I get the following result:

```
(TCDigitalVenv) MacBook-Pro-de-Hugo:TCDigital hugovillalobos$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_post_inventory_input_not_seriable (inventory.tests.TestInventoryActionInputNoSeriable)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/TCDigitalProject/TCDigitalBackend/TCDigital/inventory/tests.py", line 31, in test_post_inventory_input_not_seriable
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 401 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.083s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Which means that the request was rejected because of authentication failure. I followed [DRF authentication documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#authenticating):

```
def test_post_inventory_input_not_seriable(self):
        token = Token.objects.get(user__username='admin')
        client = APIClient()
        client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='token '+token.key)

        response = client.post('/api/inventory/execute_action/', {
            'action': 'input',
            'repository': self.repository.id,
            'product': self.not_seriable_product.id,
            'amount': 1,
        })
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        ...
```

But I get this error:

```
(TCDigitalVenv) MacBook-Pro-de-Hugo:TCDigital hugovillalobos$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_post_inventory_input_not_seriable (inventory.tests.TestInventoryActionInputNoSeriable)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/TCDigitalProject/TCDigitalBackend/TCDigital/inventory/tests.py", line 23, in test_post_inventory_input_not_seriable
    token = Token.objects.get(user__username='admin')
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/TCDigitalProject/TCDigitalBackend/TCDigitalVenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/TCDigitalProject/TCDigitalBackend/TCDigitalVenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 408, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token.DoesNotExist: Token matching query does not exist.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.046s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I don't know if I have to create the user everytime I run the test, of wether there is a way to avoid the need for authentication for testing.

Answer (score 2):

You should create user for each of your test cases to be able to login somebody.
But, you can login him much easier:

```
admin = User.objects.create_user(...)
self.client.force_login(admin)
response = client.post(...)
```

This will forcibly [login user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login) during your test and api will consider him logged in (no need to send headers and stuff with request).

`self.client` is basically `APIClient()` for current `TestCase`.